# Get ID of inserted record then update another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, insert, migration

## Information

I am currently migrating legacy data from an old database to a new database, where the schema has changed.

**Old Schema**

```
Table Event
    PK_EventID

View OldVideoConferenceParticiants
    FK_EventID
    FK_ParticipantID
```

**New Schema**

```
Table Event
    PK_EventID
    FK_VideoConferenceID

Table VideoConference
    PK_VideoConferenceID

Table VideoConferenceParticipants
    PK_VideoConferenceParticipantID
    FK_VideoConferenceID
```

What I want to do, is:

1. Group all old participants based on their eventID. (done)
2. For each eventID, insert a new VideoConference and then set the VideoConference FK for each event to their respective newly inserted VideoConferenceID. (*I can't figure this one out*)
3. For each old participant, get the corresponding VideoConferenceID and create a new VideoConferenceParticipant.  (done)

**Problem**
I think I might need to use MERGE but all of my attemps thus far have been disastrous. I've also tried using

```
INSERT ... OUPUT INSERTED.VideconferenceID
```

...but I can't get it right. I need to have both the EventID and the VideoConferenceID side by side somehow, which insert does not allow me to do.

Could someone please give me some guidance on how to accomplish #2 above?

Comment: It doesn't feel right, but since you're creating the table `VideoConference` from scratch, can't you just set `PK_VideoConferenceID` yourself? For example you could have `Event.FK_VideoConferenceID` equals to `Event.PK_EventID`, then insert `Event.FK_VideoConferenceID` into `VideoConference`.

Comment: With [insert identity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx) set to `on` before inserting, and back to `off` after.

Comment: Yeah, that's a simpler solution... i dont love it either, but itll work.